# How to change from Left to Right Layout using HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css

how to make change in the css part such that my layout should be in horizontal way .

Currently according to my css part it displays the content in row wise that is in vertical formate I want to chage it to horizontal way with only three column?

Basically I took code from here how I can change it to left to right?

```
https://codepen.io/qq7886/pen/MypEvw
```

```
    .masonry {
      /* Masonry container */
      -webkit-column-count: 4;
      -moz-column-count: 4;
      column-count: 4;
      -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
      -moz-column-gap: 1em;
      column-gap: 1em;
      margin: 1.5em;
      padding: 0;
      -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
      -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
      column-gap: 1.5em;
      font-size: 0.85em;
    }

    .item {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 1em;
      margin: 0 0 1.5em;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: 1s ease all;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
    }



    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count 2;
        column-count: 2;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
      .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
      .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
      }
    }
```

I added this property `display: flex;` but all the content in same row but I  want only 3 column

Answer (score 1):

I failed to find any kind of alignment property in CSS3 columns. I doubt that there's one tbh.

If I were you I would follow what Navalex suggested and went with "flexbox". https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35/

You can also try something like Bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: actually bootstrap uses Flexbox on their grid system

Comment: Yeah. It does. I just find it a little bit easier to manage, due to its somewhat strict structure.

Answer (score 0):

I hope The Answer should be something like this: 
try to add 4 first line of masonry class and change columns-count to 3.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
   background: #f2f2f2;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom:60px;
}

h4{
  text-align:center; 
  line-height:80px;
  font-weight:normal;

}

.masonry { /* Masonry container */
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2em; /* [1] Add some gap between rows and columns */
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax( 200px, 1fr ) ); /* [2] Make columns adjust according to the available viewport */
  grid-auto-rows: 250px; /* [3] Set the height for implicitly-created r */
  
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count:3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
   margin: 1.5em;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
 -webkit-transition:1s ease all;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}
.item img{max-width:100%;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Responsive Masonry Grid</h1>
<p>A pure CSS-only responsive masonry.</p>
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    1
    <img src="http://www.pixeden.com/media/k2/galleries/468/001-business-card-clip-brand-mock-up-vol-20-psd.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    2
    <img src="http://www.graphicsfuel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/branding-mockup-psd.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    3
    <img src="http://www.pixeden.com/media/k2/galleries/511/001-business-card-mockup-vol-22-box-brand-psd.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    4
    <img src="http://freede.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/6546546542.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    5
    <img src="https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/mockup/23.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    6
    <img src="http://jquerypluginplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Psd_Business_Card_MockUp.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    7
    <img src="http://www.pixeden.com/media/k2/galleries/754/001-businesscard-mockup-presentation-psd-free-resource.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    8
    <img src="http://designdecoding.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/001-a4-paper-brand-stationery-isometric-print-mock-up-psd-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    9
    <img src="http://www.blugraphic.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Folded-Page-Mockup1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    10
    <img src="http://cdn.designinstruct.com/files/542-free-branding-identity-mockups/29-branding-identity-mock-up-vol-8-full.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    11
    <img src="http://www.thomsoon.com/img/portfolio/7clean/7-clean-business-card-mockup-psd-3.jpg">
  </div>
    <div class="item">
    12
    <img src="http://www.pixeden.com/media/k2/galleries/640/001-business-card-cardboard-mockup-presentation-wall-free-psd.jpg">
  </div>

  


</div>
<h4>Photo from <a href="https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=mock+up&espv=2&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz:m&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidx5_s29DLAhVIj5QKHRblBf8QpwUIEw&dpr=1&biw=1920&bih=971"> google</a>.</h4>
```

Credit goes to https://w3bits.com/css-grid-masonry/